# Is there a way to define a GraphQL fragment using TypeGraphQL?

Tags: graphql, typegraphql, graphql-fragments

Couldn't find anything related to GraphQL fragments in the TypGraphQL docs. Am I missing something or is it not possible to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41572799/6124657

Answer (score 0):

TypeGraphQL is a server-side library. GraphQL fragment is a client-side feature.

So no, there's no way to do that in any server-side library, even in reference `graphql-js` implementation.